# Polymer class property declaration type

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, types, polymer

So, I am basically from **Angular**, **React** background and have started to work with **Polymer** 1 month ago,
Just like all JS frameworks and libraries, **Polmer 3.0** also utilizes **ES6**, so for instance if I have `XCustom` polymer class having a property `user` declared on it followed by its type.

So, if we talk about TS(typescript) then if we declare any property in a class and if we don't know its type then we just write `any`. like this `user:any` .

Does any one know polymer way of doing it?

```
  class XCustom extends Polymer.Element {
    static get properties() {
      return {
        user: String,
      }
    }
  }
```

Above snippet is a **polymer** class having a `user` property declared on it, but the only types available I know till so far are `Object`, `String`, `Number`.

Comment: imo, polymer is a tool and the language is TS, so you follow the rules for the language.

Comment: Yes, but polymer do provide typing, I am just giving an example of TS, but if polymer supports typing then I am wondering is there **any** keyword as a type in polmer, as we have in TS.